# GUI management tool for running git repositories

Tags: git

I have a hosting account at Media Temple and would like to host my own git repos on there. Is there a nice GUI tool I can install which will let me create repos, manage permissions etc?

I think it would need to be PHP based as I can't install Ruby.

Comment: Why not just use Github? It solves the same problem, but it's already done for you. Plus, I think the web page is open-source, if you want to take a look. It's Ruby AFAIK with a little NodeJS.

Comment: Git hub is too expensive. I want 20 plus private projects

Comment: Then why use a webserver if it's private? Why not just use a client-side GUI with gitosis hosting your stuff. Which one depends on your OS (Linux, Mac, Windows).

Comment: You can try [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/plans) : it provides unlimited public and private repositories for free (but limited to 5 different users).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Gitblit for managing mine git repos! Gitblit is the best suite for small group.

http://gitblit.com

Answer (score 0):

Try GitLab
GitLab is an incredibly powerful open source code collaboration platform, git repository manager, issue tracker and code reviewer. It integrates with issue trackers, continuous integration services and our Enterprise Edition has phenomenal LDAP and Active Directory support.

https://about.gitlab.com/

Answer (score 0):

stash is a tool that can manage your git repository on your server and it is can be found here.

https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash